# Color Outliers in LineChart

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am generating line charts with the following syntax:

```
df2 = df2[['runtime','per','dev','var']]

op = f"/tmp/image.png"
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='darkslategrey')
df2.plot(x='runtime',xlabel="Date", kind='line', marker='o',linewidth=2,alpha=.7,subplots=True,color=['khaki', 'lightcyan','thistle'])

plt.style.use('dark_background')
plt.suptitle(f'Historical Data:', fontsize=12,fontname = 'monospace')

#file output
plt.savefig(op, transparent=False,bbox_inches="tight")

plt.close('all')
```

Where `df2` dataframe sample:

```
     runtime    per   dev   var
1 2021-05-28  50.85  2.11  2.13
1 2021-05-30  50.85  2.11  2.13
1 2021-06-02  51.13  2.16  2.11
1 2021-06-04  51.13  2.16  2.11
1 2021-06-07  51.13  2.16  2.11
1 2021-06-09  51.11  2.13  2.10
1 2021-06-10  51.11  2.13  2.10
1 2021-06-14  51.11  2.13  2.10
1 2021-06-16  51.34  2.12  2.10
1 2021-06-18  51.34  2.12  2.10
1 2021-06-21  51.34  2.12  2.10
1 2021-06-23  51.69  1.97  2.17
1 2021-06-25  51.69  1.97  2.17
1 2021-06-28  51.69  1.97  2.17
1 2021-06-30  56.46  1.74  2.14
1 2021-07-02  56.46  1.74  2.14
1 2021-07-05  56.46  1.74  2.14
1 2021-07-07  55.10  1.84  2.08
1 2021-07-09  55.10  1.84  2.08
1 2021-07-12  55.10  1.84  2.08
1 2021-07-14  54.58  1.85  2.07
1 2021-07-16  54.58  1.85  2.07
1 2021-07-19  54.58  1.85  2.07
1 2021-07-21  54.33  1.87  2.06
1 2021-07-23  54.33  1.87  2.06
1 2021-07-26  54.33  1.87  2.06
1 2021-07-28  54.98  1.91  2.19
1 2021-07-30  54.98  1.91  2.19
```

This works great.
Now, I would like to change the color of points if their values are "abnormal", specifically if per < 90.00 or per > 10.00, or if dev < 10.00 or if var < 10.00 to color the point RED.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of drawing the 3 subplots in one call, they could be drawn one-by-one. First draw the subplot as before, and on top of it a scatter plot, only with the "abnormal" points. `zorder=3` makes sure that the scatter dots appear on top of the existing dots.

Here is some example code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'runtime': pd.date_range('20210101', freq='D', periods=100),
                    'per': np.random.uniform(1, 99, 100),
                    'dev': np.random.uniform(1, 11, 100),
                    'var': np.random.uniform(2, 11, 100)})
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize=(6, 10), facecolor='darkslategrey', sharex=True)
for ax, column, color, (min_normal, max_normal) in zip(axs,
                                                       ['per', 'dev', 'var'],
                                                       ['khaki', 'lightcyan', 'thistle'],
                                                       [(10, 90), (-np.inf, 10), (-np.inf, 10)]):
    df2.plot(x='runtime', xlabel="Date", y=column, ylabel=column,
             kind='line', marker='o', linewidth=2, alpha=.7, color=color, legend=False, ax=ax)
    df_abnormal = df2[(df2[column] < min_normal) | (df2[column] > max_normal)]
    df_abnormal.plot(x='runtime', xlabel="Date", y=column, ylabel=column,
                     kind='scatter', marker='o', color='red', legend=False, zorder=3, ax=ax)
plt.style.use('dark_background')
plt.suptitle(f'Historical Data:', fontsize=12, fontname='monospace')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: pandas line plot with marked outliers]

Comment: Wow. yes. thank you, this makes a lot of sense.